# Netbeans IDE - How to change the colour of tabs/spaces

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

[image: Netbeans Weirdness]

Please note the shade darker than the background. I would like to make this the same colour as the background. I've gone through each entry in a the 'appearance' and can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather erase these obsolete whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot]

Go to Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors->Highlighting. Indent Guide Lines is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Trailing whitespace is what you are looking for. It's under the same menu

Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors->Highlighting